# Did the derivation of self inductance equation overcalculate winding number?

Tags: magnetic-fields, inductance

Let $L , I , \phi$ are self inductance , current and magnetic flux (created by each loop) of a solenoid with $n$ turns . $r$ is the radius of those loops . We have , $LI=n \phi = nAB $  [$A=\pi r^2$]

Now according to textbook , "As there are n loops ,  $\displaystyle B=\frac{n\mu_oI}{2r}$ .

Substituting $B$ , $\displaystyle LI=nA\times\frac{n\mu_oI}{2r}\Rightarrow L=\frac{n^2\mu_o \pi r}{2}$ "

We considered the fact of n loops when we multiplied $n$ with $\phi$ . Again we multiplied $n$ while calculating $B$ .

In the equation $n\phi=nAB$ , $B$ represents magnetic flux density *caused by each loop* . On the other hand , in the equation $\displaystyle B=\frac{n\mu_oI}{2r}$ , $B$ represents magnetic flux density *caused by all loops* . We calculated $\displaystyle L=\frac{n^2\mu_o \pi r}{2}$ considering the winding number fact twice . So shouldn't  be the equation wrong ?

(The question other users are refering as "original" of this question (asked by myself a few weeks ago) isn't totally about self-inductance . This question is regarding to deduction of a equation for self-inductance .)

Answer (score 0):

On one hand, the flux $\Phi$ seen by the solenoid is $n*\phi$ where $n$ is the number of turns and $\phi$ the flux seen by each turn. I think this is straightforward : if there are two turns, the flux is counted twice.

On the other hand, the magnetic flux induced by one turn is $B*S$ or ($\int \vec{B}.d\vec{S}$). The flux of two turns is twice the flux of one turn.

You should note that the point 1) is relative to the flux and the point 2) is relative to the currents. You can consider : the cause is the current (shared by all turns), that create a magnetic flux (consequence) ; however, the magnetic flux is also seen by each turn (which is like the voltage point of view).

So yes, the number of turns is counted twice, but it is right to do so.

You could also consider a n-turn solenoid, and a 1-turn coil which would be coincident.
A current flows in the solenoid, therefore the magnetic flux is : $n*B*S$. The flux seen by the 1-turn coil is $n*B*S$ : the mutual inductance is function of the number of turns of the n-turn solenoid (emitter). Reciprocally, if the current flows in the 1-turn coil, the flux is just $B*S$ but is seen by the n-turn coil $n$ times :  the mutual inductance if function of the number of spires of the n-turn solenoid (which is the receiver here).